# Short story about two teens stuck on a barren moon

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this in the 1970s:

- Two teens were stuck on a barren moon
- They inflate some kind of plastic bubble and line it with some kind of green rubber and use it to get off the Moon
- They may or may not have had to slow the Moon's rotation by using pieces of solid rocket fuel

Comment: Can you add some more details please? You may also be interested in reading this guideline on [How to ask a good story-ID question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267)